# Vue не видит путь к изображению

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Всем доброго времени суток. Не могу понять, почему в VUE 3.0 один и тот-же путь работает по разному.
Дело в том, что я пытаюсь задать путь к изображению в теге img такими способами:

Первый на прямую, но мне такой вариант не подходит, т.к. разные изображение приходят от сервера и каждый раз создавать тег мне нужно:

```
<img id="weatherIcon" ref="imgComponent" src="../imgs/Clouds.png" />
```

Второй раз я пытаюсь это всё обработать при рендеринге элемента:

```
mounted() {
const imgComponent = this.$refs.imgComponent;
imgComponent.src = "../imgs/Clouds.png";
},
```

Но этот путь уже не работает, как быть?

Comment: :src="newSrc" - и далее когда и как угодно определяйте значение newSrc. (но вам необходимо посмотреть, например на Тюбе обучающие материалы для понимания происходящих процессов между DOM и вашим script, и лучше сразу изучать более гибкий  Vue3 Composition API)

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще. Нужно было импортировать изображение таким образом:

```
import Clouds from "../imgs/Clouds.png";
```